# How to reset user history with logout in react navigation react navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation and Firebase for authentication for a user to move to different screens in my react navigation app.

I created a logout function that signs the user out and takes them to the login screen. However on the upper left corner my app gives the user the option to go  back into app without the need to log back in with button labelled as the name of the screen they just logged out of. Is there a way to disable this?

Here is my logout screen :

```js
export default function ProductScreen({ navigation }) {
  const logOutPress = () => {
    try {
      auth()
        .signOut()
        .then(() => {
          navigation.navigate("Login"), alert("You have signed out");
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("err", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => logOutPress()}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Log Out</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Also here is my `app.js` where I house my react navigation and Firebase :

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users");
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        usersRef
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((document) => {
            const userData = document.data();
            setLoading(false);
            setUser(userData);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            setLoading(false);
          });
      } else {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {user ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Products">
            {(props) => <ProductScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          </>
        )}
        <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Payment" component={PaymentScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Lawn Care" component={LawnCareScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Reset Password" component={ResetPasswordScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Car Detail" component={CarDetailScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to reset your whole navigation stack. Check this out.. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset

Answer (score 2):

To disable user from navigating back to the previous screen after logout you need to clear the stack of the stack navigator in the Product Screen . I have provided the code sample below

```html
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
export default function ProductScreen({ navigation }) {
  const logOutPress = () => {
    try {
      auth()
        .signOut()
        .then(() => {
          const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Login" })],
          });
          navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
          alert("You have signed out");
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("err", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => logOutPress()}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Log Out</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this code in the index.js to logout :

```
<Stack.Screen  name="Main" component={Main} options={({ navigation,route }) => ({
                    title: '', headerLeft: () => (<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => (_singout())}
                      style={{ margin: 16, marginTop: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0 }}>
                      <Image resizeMode="contain" source={mylogoutImage} style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>),
                  })} />
```

and in `_singout()` function clear my asyncStorage.

I hope to help you.